# Identifying a set of real numbers which is associated with a square matrix A

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1\\2&4\end{bmatrix}$ Find the eigen values of $A$. Then identify the set $\{a\in\mathbb R : \lim_{n\to\infty}a^nA^n$ exists and different from zero}.
I have find the eigenvalues of $A$ which are 5 and 2. Then $A=P^{-1}DP$ where $D=\begin{bmatrix}5&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$. Then $a^nA^n=a^nP^{-1}D^nP$ and this will tend to zero if $a\leq\frac{1}{10}$. Now what to do if we want to have limit different from zero? One possibility is $a=\frac{1}{5}$. If $|a|\leq\frac{1}{5}$ then limit exists but it will converge to zero. If $|a|\geq\frac{1}{5}$ then limit does not exists. So I think the only possible value of $a$ is $\frac{1}{5}$. So any help on this one?

Comment: I think you have solved the problem.

Comment: You think or you are sure?

Comment: Well, your eigenvalues are correct; your $D$ is correct; your formula for $a^nA^n$ is correct (although you should say "there exists $P$ such that..."); $1/10$ is irrelevant (though not wrong); your $|a|\le1/5$ should be $|a|<1/5$; and you should explicitly say what happens if $a=-1/5$. So, modulo a little tidying up, yes, you have solved the problem.